# concatenate variable and string in windows batch file command inside quotes

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to loop through a directory and do the following to every jpg file:

```
magick "C:\InputFolder\001.jpg" -trim "C:\OutputFolder\001.jpg"
```

So far I have this:

```
 for %%f in (*.jpg) do
 magick "C:\InputFolder\%%~nf.jpg" -fuzz 50% -trim "C:\OutputFolder\%%~nf.jpg"
```

But that does not work, how do I get the %%~nf variable inside the quoted string?

Comment: do it in one line or add a `(` at the end of the `for` line to open a command block and a `)` as last line to close the command block. See `for /?` for correct syntax. Vote to close as "typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through a given directory I recommend `for /r`.

In batch:

```
@echo off

set "des=C:\OutputFolder"

for /r "C:\InputFolder" %%A in (*.jpg) do (
    magick "%%A" -fuzz 50%% -trim "%des%\%%~nxA"
)
```

(you'll probably need to double-up the percent sign on `-fuzz 50%` for batch to process it).

From command:

```
for /r "C:\InputFolder" %A in (*.jpg) do (magick "%A" -fuzz 50% -trim "C:\OutputFolder\%~nxA")
```

The last set of parentheses aren't necessary but I like having them.

Reference: [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [Parameters/Arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: `for /R` also loops through sub-directories, hence the whole directory tree, not sure whether the OP wants that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Parenthesis in order to have code that spans more than one line after the DO statement whether you are using the CLI or writing a batch script.

Assuming you are writing a CMD Script (as you have %% instead of %) this woudl do the needful:

```
@(
  SetLocal
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Dst=C:\OutputFolder"
)

FOR %%A in (
  "C:\InputFolder\*.jpg"
) DO (
  ECHO. Magick "%%~fA" -fuzz 50%% -trim "%_Dst%\%%~nA"
  Magick "%%~fA"-fuzz 50%% -trim "%_Dst%\%%~nA"
)
```

If you are at the CLI (CMD) Window you could paste in this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "_Dst=C:\OutputFolder"
FOR %A in (
  "C:\InputFolder\*.jpg"
) DO (
  ECHO. Magick "%~fA" -fuzz 50% -trim "%_Dst%\%~nA"
  REM Magick "%~fA" -fuzz 50% -trim "%_Dst%\%~nA"
)
```